# Trying to understand interfaces

Tags: c#, interface

I'm quite new in C# and struggles to understand the use and benefit of interfaces.
I was given the example below (Example 1) to study the use of interface.
My problem is that the program works as well without interface (Example 2).
So what is the benefit of the interface in this example?

**Example 1:**

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    interface IShape
    {
        double Area();
        double Perimeter();
    }

    class Circle : IShape
    {
        private double radius;
        public Circle(double radius)
        {
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        public double Area()
        {
            return Math.PI * radius * radius;
        }

        public double Perimeter()
        {
            return 2 * Math.PI * radius;
        }
    }

    class Rectangle : IShape
    {
        private double length;
        private double width;

        public Rectangle(double length, double width)
        {
            this.length = length;
            this.width = width;
        }

        public double Area()
        {
            return length * width;
        }

        public double Perimeter()
        {
            return 2 * ( length + width );
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IShape circle = new Circle(5);
            IShape rectangle = new Rectangle(10, 20);;

            Console.WriteLine("Cirkelns area är {0}", circle.Area());
            Console.WriteLine("Cirkelns omkrets är {0}", circle.Perimeter());
            Console.WriteLine("Rektangelns area är {0}", rectangle.Area());
            Console.WriteLine("Rektangelns omkrets är {0}", rectangle.Perimeter());
        }
    }
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    class Circle
    {
        private double radius;
        public Circle(double radius)
        {
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        public double Area()
        {
            return Math.PI * radius * radius;
        }

        public double Perimeter()
        {
            return 2 * Math.PI * radius;
        }
    }

    class Rectangle
    {
        private double length;
        private double width;

        public Rectangle(double length, double width)
        {
            this.length = length;
            this.width = width;
        }

        public double Area()
        {
            return length * width;
        }

        public double Perimeter()
        {
            return 2 * ( length + width );
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Circle circle = new Circle(5);
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(10, 20);

            Console.WriteLine("Cirkelns area är {0}", circle.Area());
            Console.WriteLine("Cirkelns omkrets är {0}", circle.Perimeter());
            Console.WriteLine("Rektangelns area är {0}", rectangle.Area());
            Console.WriteLine("Rektangelns omkrets är {0}", rectangle.Perimeter());
        }
    }
}
```

I studied and compered the two examples to try to understand what the interface is doing and why I shall use it

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Introducing the Class Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/4fcadw4a(v=vs.100)) and [Interfaces - define behavior for multiple types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/interfaces)

Comment: [Suggested reading:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802573/interfaces-whats-the-point) and also [there is this existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250458/whats-the-use-of-interfaces-if-i-have-to-implement-all-the-members-elsewhere-an).  There is literally gobs and gobs of existing information here.  Its almost like were have been building a database of useful programming info.

Comment: real McCoys dont use interfaces.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you were interested in the sum of areas of n shapes, you **can't** just iterate over a list of mixed contents, like `List<Circle Or Rectangle>` ... so you will just use a `List<IShape>`. Then, you can just call the "area()" functions of whatever is in that list, if it implements the interface function.

Comment: Thanks, really good to know, I'm sure I will have use for it in the future

Answer (score -1):

The interfaces are used to make some properties or atributes required.

Yes, the code will work without any interface.

But using the interface make sure that all of the objects are implementing the required atributes (properties, functions, etc...). The interface makes mandatory to implement some atributes or properties or functions.

for your example, the interface is used to make sure that all of your objects (Circle , Rectangle) have the Area and Perimeter functions.

Comment: Thank you Victor, this was impotrant info!